# How to check what is occupying disk space for azure service plan?

Tags: azure, azure-app-service-plans

I have a service plan on premium that I want to move to the free tier. File system storage says that I do have 1.09 GB, so I cannot do that (free is limited to 1 GB). I do have only a simple web application (just a test really) that can't occupy that much space. What can it be that occupies the disk and more importantly how can I check or monitor what does occupy the space?

Answer (score 1):

You can see what is in your App Service if you open the FTP file location. You will see two folders; "LogFiles" and "Site".

You can find your FTP url on the Dashboard of your web site. Also note, that when you enter your username, it will be something like "websitename\username". If you don't know your password, you can "Reset your Deployment Credentials" which is also on the dashboard (or under the Publishing section of the "All Settings" blade if you are using the http://portal.azure.com)

Two things may be taking up your space... log data or web site dependencies.

Comment: I have actually discovered that already, but deleting everything did not help... I even deleted one of my apps and it was still showing 1.09 GB... So I had to delete the whole service plan

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? Currently experiencing the smae problem...